# CASE statement still returning multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, case

the following query is returning two rows per ID.

```
select distinct ID,
count (COURSE_IDENTIFICATION) as tot_course_id,

COUNT(case when course_level = 'G'
     then (COURSE_IDENTIFICATION)
     else '0'end) count_grad,

COUNT (case when course_level = 'U'
       then (COURSE_IDENTIFICATION)
       else '0'end) count_under

from ods.STUDENT_COURSE

where ACADEMIC_PERIOD = '201890'
and COURSE_BILLING_CREDITS >0.0
group by ID, course_level
order by 1
```

I receive the following results:

```
ID      |TOT_COURSE_NUM |COUNT_GRAD |COUNT_UNDER
-------------------------------------------------
12345   |1              |1          |1
12345   |2              |2          |2
```

Is there any way to ensure both grad and undergrad totals are counted in the same row?

Comment: Yes, easy: remove `course_level` from `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You can also remove the `DISTINCT` keyword from your select.  It isn't hurting anything, but `GROUP BY` will already return distinct results.

Comment: That's a case _expression_, not a statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your group by statement, you are specifying `course_level`.  Remove `course_level` from your group by statement and it should consolidate the rows.

Comment: @Lyndey . . . It is ironic that this is the accepted answer, when implementing this doesn't actually return what you intend.

Answer (score 5):

Your immediate problem is that `course_level` is in the `group by`.  A secondary problem is that the `count()` is incorrect.  I think this should be sufficient:

```
select ID,
       count(*) as tot_course_id,
       sum(case when course_level = 'G' then 1 else 0 end) as count_grad,
       sum(case when course_level = 'U' then 1 else 0 end) as count_under
from ods.STUDENT_COURSE sc
where ACADEMIC_PERIOD = '201890' and
      COURSE_BILLING_CREDITS > 0.0
group by ID
order by 1;
```

`count(<expression>)` counts the number of non-`NULL` values.  Your `else '0'` is still non-null, so it gets counted.  `sum()` is a simple way to take care of this.

This version assumes that `COURSE_IDENTIFICATION` is not `NULL`.  That seems like a reasonable assumption in a table called `STUDENT_COURSE`.  It is easily modified to handle `NULL` values.

And, `select distinct` is almost never appropriate with `group by`.

Comment: Good eye on the `ELSE 0`

Comment: Good eye on the `else '0'`. However, the `then` part you wrote implicitly is not equivalent to what the OP wrote. If `course_identification` can be null, then the OP's code will not count it; yours will.

Comment: @mathguy . . . I knew that.  I just didn't explain it.  I added an explanation.

Comment: "I knew" is not the same as "I thought of it"; but regardless, what you know doesn't help anyone who reads your answer, if you don't also write it up.